# How can I use a .bmp file and create a Texture in Unity at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, bmp, texture2d

I'm working in a Unity Project where the user choose image files (in `.bmp` format) that is used to make a `Texture2D` and pasted to a model, I create the next code, I work fine with `.png` and `.jpg` file, but when I try load `.bmp` I got only a (I assume) default texture with a red "?" symbol, so I think is for the image format, how can I create a Texture using `.bmp` files at run-time?

this is my code:

```
public static Texture2D LoadTexture(string filePath)
{
    Texture2D tex = null;
    byte[] fileData;

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        tex.LoadImage(fileData);
    }

    return tex;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Texture2D.LoadImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html) function is only used to load PNG/JPG image byte array into a `Texture`. It doesn't support `.bmp` so the red symbol which usually means corrupted or unknown image is expected.

To load `.bmp` image format in Unity, you have to read and understand the `.bmp` format specification then implement a method that converts its byte array into Unity's Texture. Luckily, this has already been done by another person. Grab the *`BMPLoader`* plugin [*here*](https://pastebin.com/fykWMpuB).

To use it, include the `using B83.Image.BMP` namespace:

```
public static Texture2D LoadTexture(string filePath)
{
    Texture2D tex = null;
    byte[] fileData;

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        BMPLoader bmpLoader = new BMPLoader();
        //bmpLoader.ForceAlphaReadWhenPossible = true; //Uncomment to read alpha too

        //Load the BMP data
        BMPImage bmpImg = bmpLoader.LoadBMP(fileData);

        //Convert the Color32 array into a Texture2D
        tex = bmpImg.ToTexture2D();
    }
    return tex;
}
```

You can also skip the `File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);` part and pass the `.bmp` image path directly to the `BMPLoader.LoadBMP` function:

```
public static Texture2D LoadTexture(string filePath)
{
    Texture2D tex = null;

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        BMPLoader bmpLoader = new BMPLoader();
        //bmpLoader.ForceAlphaReadWhenPossible = true; //Uncomment to read alpha too

        //Load the BMP data
        BMPImage bmpImg = bmpLoader.LoadBMP(filePath);

        //Convert the Color32 array into a Texture2D
        tex = bmpImg.ToTexture2D();
    }
    return tex;
}
```

Comment: Note that the BMPLoader doesn't check for mirror image bmps. This will result in them being drawn incorrectly.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg: I recently fixed a few issues with the loader due to an issue filed on [github](https://github.com/Bunny83/Utilities/blob/master/WorkInProgress/BMPLoader.cs). I've updated both versions. It does now flip the texture when the height is negative. Though this is a really rare case. Almost no image editor does use this format. I still hadn't enough time to throw enough test images against the loader. Feel free to submit an issue if you find something weird.