# How load bitmap from disk in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gdi+, system.drawing

I want to load a bitmap from disk. I am using the Bitmap class in System.Drawing, which makes it very simple.

However, when I deploy to macOS, I get an exception.

DllNotFoundException: /Users/bokken/build/ouput/Unity-Technologies/mono/external/buildscripts/add_to_build_results/monodistribution/lib/libgdiplus.dylib

Is there a simple way to load bitmaps that doesn't create this error, or alternately, how do I fix this error?

Comment: Can whoever gave the -1 say why? What's unclear about this or why isn't it useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use custom code to load a bitmap.

See here [How can I use a .bmp file and create a Texture in Unity at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975990/how-can-i-use-a-bmp-file-and-create-a-texture-in-unity-at-runtime) which solves this problem.

Note that the BMPLoader in the accepted answer doesn't draw mirror image bitmaps correctly, and the code probably should be tested thoroughly for other possible problems.

Surprised Unity doesn't have a built-in capability to load images outside of PNG and JPG.

Answer (score 0):

Unity is cross platform, but C# .NET Framework is not.

So to keep your game cross platform, you either use other cross platform libraries (somewhere published on the Internet), or stick to capabilities of Unity.

Unity provides, for example a `Texture2D` class, that can be a workaround. Some more info from [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/51414/bitmaps-in-unity.html)

Comment: I am using Texture2Ds internally, and the bitmap after being loaded is converted into a Texture2D. I simply need to load the bitmap from disk.

Comment: Bitmap is nothing but an array of bytes, and Texture2D gives an opportunity to load it. Follow the link I posted. `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class is Windows only

Comment: I've followed the link, but it's not clear at all to me how to apply that to the question.

Comment: You cannot make a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, unless you're on Windows. You can use `Texture2D.GetPixels32` of Unity to get `Color32[]` which is essentially a bitmap (a data structure, not `System.Drawing.Bitmap`). You can use this array for your needs (transform it into another object, or a `byte[]` or whatever.

Comment: Yes, but how do I load the bitmap from disk into the Texture2D to begin with? GetPixels32() is used once the texture has the data.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg no hard to search [for it](http://answers.unity.com/answers/802424/view.html) either

Comment: That link is to loading a PNG or JPG, not a bitmap.